# Book on Riemannian geometry

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I am looking for good books on manifolds, Riemannian geometry. Can you help me? I am a undergraduate level student.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19505/riemannian-geometry-introductory-text ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499945/need-help-finding-a-good-book-on-riemann-geometry ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295773/riemannian-geometry-book-to-complement-general-relativity-course ;

Answer (score 2):

John Lees Introduction to Smooth Manifolds is a good place to start. He covers the fundamentals of the subject, and the beginning half is filled with really important concepts required to better understand Riemannian manifolds. He also has a book called Riemannian Manifolds which is pretty good, but quite advanced in comparison to the smooth manifolds book.